# Pandas aggregating across time windows with user logs

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to take a dataframe of logs and aggregate counts across time windows, specifically before a Purchase. The goal is to create features that can be used to predict a future purchase.

Here is my original df

```
user_id activity_date activity_type
0       2013-07-11    EmailOpen
0       2013-07-11    FormSubmit
0       2013-07-15    EmailOpen
0       2013-07-17    Purchase
0       2013-07-18    EmailOpen
```

and I would like my result to look like:

```
user_id EmailOpen_count FormSubmit_count Days_since_start Purchase
0       2               1                6                1
0       1               0                1                0
```

The above idea is I have aggregated before the purchase, and since that user had only one purchase, the next row will aggregate everything after the last purchase.

I tried to extract the Purchase dates first and then do an iterative approach but ran it all night with no success. Here's how I was going to extract the dates, but even this took way too long and I am sure that building the new dataframe would have taken millennia:

```py
purchase_dict = {}
for user in list_of_users:
    # Stores list of days when purchase was made for each user.
    days_bought = list(df[df['user_id'] == user][df['activity_type'] == 'Purchase']['activity_date'])
    purchase_dict[user] = days_bought
```

I'm wondering if there is a semi-efficient way with groupbys, agg, time_between, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Scott, can you please update the post with your code that you've tried? It's a lot easier to help when we can all see what was already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a bit clunky, and needing some column renaming at the end, but this appears to work for me (with new testing data):

```py
user_id activity_date activity_type
0       2013-07-11    EmailOpen
0       2013-07-11    FormSubmit
0       2013-07-15    EmailOpen
0       2013-07-17    Purchase
0       2013-07-18    EmailOpen   
1       2013-07-12    Purchase
1       2013-07-12    FormSubmit
1       2013-07-15    EmailOpen
1       2013-07-18    Purchase
1       2013-07-18    EmailOpen   
2       2013-07-09    EmailOpen
2       2013-07-10    Purchase
2       2013-07-15    EmailOpen
2       2013-07-22    Purchase
2       2013-07-23    EmailOpen
```

```py
# Convert to datetime
df['activity_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['activity_date'])
# Create shifted flag to identify purchase
df['x'] = (df['activity_type'] == 'Purchase').astype(int).shift().fillna(method='bfill')
# Calculate time window as cumsum of this shifted flag
df['time_window'] = df.groupby('user_id')['x'].cumsum()
# Pivot to count activities by user ID and time window
df2 = df.pivot_table(values='activity_date', index=['user_id', 'time_window'], 
                     columns='activity_type', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)

# Create separate table of days elapsed by user ID & time window
time_elapsed = ( df.groupby(['user_id', 'time_window'])['activity_date'].max() 
                 - df.groupby(['user_id', 'time_window'])['activity_date'].min() )

# Merge dataframes
df3 = df2.join(time_elapsed)
```

yields

```
                     EmailOpen  FormSubmit  Purchase activity_date
user_id time_window                                               
0       0.0                  2           1         1        6 days
        1.0                  1           0         0        0 days
1       0.0                  0           0         1        0 days
        1.0                  1           1         1        6 days
        2.0                  1           0         0        0 days
2       0.0                  1           0         1        1 days
        1.0                  1           0         1        7 days
        2.0                  1           0         0        0 days
```

---

Edit per comments:

To add in time elapsed by type of activity:

```py
time_since_activity = ( df.groupby(['user_id', 'time_window'])['activity_date'].max() 
                      - df.groupby(['user_id', 'time_window', 'activity_type'])['activity_date'].max() )

df4 = df3.join(time_since_activity.unstack('activity_type'), rsuffix='_time')
```

yielding

```
                     EmailOpen  FormSubmit  ...  FormSubmittime Purchasetime
user_id time_window                         ...                             
0       0.0                  2           1  ...          6 days       0 days
        1.0                  1           0  ...             NaT          NaT
1       0.0                  0           0  ...             NaT       0 days
        1.0                  1           1  ...          6 days       0 days
        2.0                  1           0  ...             NaT          NaT
2       0.0                  1           0  ...             NaT       0 days
        1.0                  1           0  ...             NaT       0 days
        2.0                  1           0  ...             NaT          NaT
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Really nice code; I learned a lot. Thanks so much!

Comment: Trying your approach, I was able to do a little more feature engineering finding the times since every action type with `time_since_activity = df.groupby(['user_id', 'time_window'])['activity_date'].max() - df.groupby(['user_id', 'time_window', 'activity_type'])['activity_date'].max()
` but am having trouble appending those values as features to the df. Any help would be amazing! :)

Comment: @Scott Glad it worked for you. Please consider upvoting / accepting if it was helpful.

Comment: Regarding your second comment -- the issue here is that your `time_since_activity` dataframe has a different index structure so you can't just append. But you can join it by reshaping, similar to the first problem; see the edited answer.